# Connect to LAN IP of remote device modem through 4G modems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem, wan

I am trying to setup a connection between my computer and a remote networked device. My computer (LAN IP 192.168.0.1) is connected to a 4G modem (LAN IP 192.168.0.2). This modem connects to a WAN and has IP 10.100.1.248.

At the remote side there is another 4G modem (LAN IP 192.168.0.3) connected to the same WAN with IP 10.100.1.247. This modem is finally connected to the remote device (LAN IP 192.168.0.4).

I have set up a static route from my computer to the WAN subnet (10.100.1.X) through the local 4G modem and can now ping the remote modem's WAN address. How would I then connect to the remote device (.4)? I have tried setting up custom routes on the two modems specifying that traffic destined for 192.168.0.4 should be forwarded out of the WAN port at the local modem & out the LAN port at the remote modem, however this hasn't worked.

Comment: The scheme is PC (192.168.0.1) - 4G (192.168.0.2 - NAT 10.100.1.248) - 4G (NAT 10.100.1.247 - LAN IP 192.168.0.4) - device (192.168.0.4). So you need to create a bridge/VPN between modems to connect your separate LANs... I doubt they can this.

Comment: You may: 1) Set modem2 to move the device to DMZ. If modem2 cannot DMZ then map all ports needed to access the device to it. 2) When you need to access the device you simply access modem2's WAN address (10.100.1.247).

Comment: Thank you for the info, will try this. The modems actually do support a VPN connection but will set that up if your second suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: When you'll build VPN connection then check if it can operate in bridge mode (both LANs are set to the same subnet). If not you would reconfigure LAN for one of modems to another subnet (192.168.1.0/24 for example) and add routes via VPN interface to remote LAN subnet on both modems.